# Advice on API Gateway Usage and Best Practices in a Hybrid Software Ecosystem

Tags: authentication, websocket, architecture, microservices, api-gateway

I'm seeking guidance regarding the structure and security practices of our internal software ecosystem. We have a setup consisting of 10 different applications, each serving distinct domains. Within this ecosystem, certain components are shared across applications, such as authentication (LDAP), logging, a few other business-related components (gradually those common services will increase).

From an individual application standpoint, we employ a monolithic architecture, with each app having its own backend. However, when viewed as a whole, our ecosystem resembles a microservices architecture. We've also implemented an API gateway in front of backend systems and components.

It's important to note that our apps are used internally and only accessible with local network and/or with VPN. When it comes to traffic, there are about 100-150 peak active users, resulting in relatively low traffic. Everything has to be on prem so no could options are applicable for us.

Here are my specific questions:

- Given our scenario, is the use of an API gateway logical, or is it an
  unnecessary extra layer in our architecture?
- Currently, upon successfull login, API gateway issues a JWT token to user and each subsequent request is validated by the API
  gateway and then forwarding to related backend service. Should we consider creating a dedicated authentication
  service instead?
- Our backend services placed behind the firewall and not accesible except from the API gateway. To simplify things, we are considered removing JWT authentication logic from backend services. If someone get pass through api gateway, then we will be having problem. What is thoughts on this? Should backend services also check the integrity of the token?
- There are instances where backend systems need to communicate with
  each other. Should these communications always go through the API
  gateway, or should we implement inter-service communication? What are
  the best practices in this regard?
- We might need websocket connections to different application for different reasons. Is this connections should be handled with API gateway, too? I have this in my mind that when server needs to send a message to a client, that service will make a POST request to API gateway, and then API gateway will forward that message to the client. Is this a valid approach?

I'm looking for best practices and objective insights.

Thank you in advance for your help!